# How to set up a posterior predictive test quantities (Bayesian context) to check for independent Poisson distributions?

Tags: probability, bayesian, self-study, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

Suppose we are given data $y_j \sim \text{Poi}(\lambda)$ and assume $y_j$ are iid. 
We can assume the prior distribution for $\theta$ follows $\text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$,

The posterior distribution of $\theta | y$ is also Gamma while the posterior predictive distribution is Negative Binomial.

My question is that after deriving everything above, how would you go about setting up a posterior predictive **test quantities** to check for ***independent*** Poisson distributions?

Notice that test quantity is a function of parameters and data in a Bayesian context. It is similar to a test statistic in classical statistic.

Comment: The question as it stands is pretty broad. Do you have any anticipated forms of potential dependence?

Comment: we assumed y_i are iid. And we are just asked to find a test quantity to test for this independence assumption

Comment: If the y's are actually iid *there's nothing to do*. You are checking because you anticipate the possibility *that they aren't*. But there's an infinity of infinity of ways that they can be dependent. Given that your original question about checking is *predicated* on the possibility of dependence, please look again at my question in the previous comment.